# How can I get the current transform of the presentationLayer correctly?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I've tried this:

```
CATransform3D rotationTransform = [[self.layer presentationLayer] transform];
```

This will not work, since the compiler will throw an warning and an error:

> Warning: Multiple methods "-transform"
>   found. Error: Invalid initializer.

So then I tried this:

```
CATransform3D rotationTransform = [[self.layer presentationLayer] valueForKey:@"transform"];
```

> Error: Invalid initializer.

What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-presentationLayer` returns an `id`. You need to cast it back to a CALayer:

```
CATransform3D rotationTransform = [(CALayer*)[self.layer presentationLayer] transform];
```

To be very safe, you would check first:

```
CATransform3D rotationTransform = {0};
CALayer* presentationLayer = (CALayer*)[self.layer presentationLayer];
if( [presentationLayer respondsToSelector:@selector(transform)]) {
    rotationTransform = presentationLayer.transform;
}
```

But in practice, this is going to be fine without this check.

In the second case, `-valueForKey:` also returns an `id`, which you are trying to assign to struct, which is not possible to do implicitly. You can't just cast an object pointer into a struct.

Comment: I also fixed that in the original answer which triggered this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877198/is-there-a-way-to-figure-out-how-many-degrees-an-view-is-rotated-currently-durin/878618#878618 .  He could have waited a little bit and I would have amended my answer, rather than asking a whole new question.  However, this might be useful to keep as a standalone for people Googling something similar.

Comment: Just to add here... I was struggling with this: Every Transform must take place from the point where it was set to in the last position. So that a view rotated to 15 degrees should be rotated from 15 degree  to any other angle. i.e setting the from value is very necessary otherwise you will see a transform with glitch