# Why does the transform of the presentationLayer represent the state of the finished animation, while the animation is running?

Tags: iphone, uikit, core-animation

The documentation says:

> The presentation tree contains the
>   values that are currently being
>   presented to the user as an animation
>   takes place. For example, setting a
>   new value for the backgroundColor of a
>   layer immediately changes the value in
>   the layer tree. However, the
>   backgroundColor value in the
>   corresponding layer in the
>   presentation tree will be updated with
>   the interpolated colors as they are
>   displayed to the user.

Now the truth from my hard-core 8-hours-testing in a sandbox with only one view and an animation. During the animation I ask for:

CATransform3D currentTransform = [(CALayer*)[self.layer presentationLayer] transform]

I check for m11 and m12 values of currentTransform, to calculate the current rotation angle.

When I set up to rotate 90 degrees, two things happen, while animation takes place and has not finished:

- sometimes my calculated angle based on the currentTransform is 0.0, although the view is rotated by some angle and definitely not at 0.0.
- and sometimes (most often) it's just exactly the target value of 90 degrees.

But I never get what I want: The current state in the animation. I've been searching a while on the net, and developers seem to make rarely use of this. So that's either an bug in the framework or a bug in the documentation, or my code above to obtain the current visible transform is totally wrong.

Comment: As I responded in the comments on my answer to your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877198/is-there-a-way-to-figure-out-how-many-degrees-an-view-is-rotated-currently-durin , I used the exact code posted there to poll the rotation during the animation, and it gave the correct mid-animation value every time.  You're doing something differently in your implementation that is causing you to get incorrect values.  Perhaps you could provide more detail in your question, or a link to your test application.

Answer (score 1):

I know I have pulled the frame from the presentation layer to find the location of a view on screen during animation. That definitely works.

I used it to stop the animation then update the current the view with the presentation layer frame.

It should work, I think you will need to post your specific code to figure this out.