# How to get layer point?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-animation

I am using this code to rotate a needle (like in a speedometer):

```
CALayer* layer = someView.layer;
CABasicAnimation* animation;
animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0 * M_PI];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0 * M_PI];
animation.duration = 1.0;
animation.cumulative = YES;
animation.repeatCount = 1;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"transform.rotation.z"];
```

Now my question is that during the animation i press one button at that time needle is back to move on particular point. So i must have to get last point of layer when i touch button.

How to get last point of layer?

Comment: No idea what you are trying to ask. Please rephrase the question.

Comment: Are you trying to change the needle to point to a layer's position when you push a button?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very hard to understand, but it seems like you are asking how to determine the state of a progressing animation at the moment a user presses a button.  To do this, you can get a `CALayer`'s [presentationLayer](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/presentationLayer), and query that for the current value of the property being animated.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877198/is-there-a-way-to-figure-out-how-many-degrees-an-view-is-rotated-currently-durin) show you how to determine the angle of your rotated presentationLayer.  You probably want to ignore my needlessly complex answer there.